# Fixing VBSCRIPT inaccurate mathematical results due to rounding

Tags: math, vbscript

Try running this in a .VBS file

```
MsgBox(545.14-544.94)
```

You get a neat little answer of `0.199999999999932`!

This rounding issue also occurs unfortunately in **Sin(2 * pi)** since VB can only ever see the (user defined) variable pi as accurate as *3.14159265358979*.

Is rounding it manually (and loosing accuracy) the only way to improve the result? What is the most effective way of dealing with this kind of problem?

Comment: .vbs files are VBSCRIPT, not VB6.

Comment: Floating-point arithmetic has already been discussed a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point

Comment: thanks john, you're right, but this occurs in vb6 as well.

Comment: I find this a real problem specially when you write loops and get errors. It is so strange that in VBScript you don't get to choose the datatype, worse, the interpreter forces the "wrong" type.

Comment: @JayWick, What did you end up doing to resolve this tragic problem? Do you think a scripting language such as JS or Python have it also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's the way floating point numbers work, small inaccuracies are to be expected. For nicer output it's easiest to just display the results rounded to fewer digits.

Comment: +1 It's explained very nicely here (slightly tongue in cheek but very nice explanation) http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail.aspx

Comment: the link for the above comment is: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/